# EF Simple Cross Join Not Working

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

In EF4 I'm trying to do a simple cross join, but get the error

> Unable to create a constant value of type ''. Only primitive
>   types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

The query looks like this:

```
var query =
    from t1 in _context.Table1
    from t2 in _context.Table2
    select new
    {
        t2.Name
    };
```

The type that is it blowing up on is the second in the join. I can reverse the order of the from clauses, and the second one always gives the error.

What could be causing this?

Comment: This doesn't look like a join. Also, the anonymous object seems to lack the property name.

Comment: The anonymous object will automatically use the property name if one isn't specified.

Comment: I know but haven't tried this with EF. What about the join? Usually you join two tables **on** something.

Comment: This should work fine - or at least works fine for me with EF5.

Comment: I need to do an `OR` statement in the join clause, which isn't possible with linq, so I can't do a regular join.

Comment: What database are you using? Are you enumerating the list right away for example `query.ToList()`?

Comment: SQL Server 2008, but EF is blowing up before even making the query. `query.Count()` is the first thing I'm doing with it.

Comment: @McAden Looks like I am using 5. The version on the assembly is 4.4.0.0, but the NuGet package says 5.0.0.

Comment: @McAden Apparently EF5 on .NET 4.0 is EF4... so I'll have to try upgrading the project to 4.5 and see if the issue is fixed.

Comment: @McAden It still didn't work after upgrading. :(

Comment: I assume you can query from each table just fine on their own?

Comment: Yes. I'm able to do a cross join by doing a union, but it's a big query mess.